# When is it not good to use await async?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 based project written using C#. I am aware that the best time to use `await` and `async` is when accessing external resources like pulling data from the database, accessing files, or making an HTTP request. This frees up the thread so more work is done instead for the thread to sit around waiting for code to finish.

However, I am trying to figure out at what point using `async/await` will hurt performance? Does the process of releasing the thread when `await` is called and retrieving a thread when the task complete have cost?

The code found next, is called asynchronously. In reality, that code does not need to be called asynchronously since all the code is executed in memory and no external requests are made.

```
public interface ILocator
{
    Task<Model> ExampleAsync();
}

public class Example : Controller
{
    public ILocator Locator { get; set; }

    public Example(ILocator locator)
    {
        Locator = locator;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Example()
    {
        Model model = await Locator.ExampleAsync();

        return View(model);
    }
}

public class Locator : ILocator
{
    pubilc Task ExampleAsync()
    {
        Example model = new Example();
        model.Status = "New";

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Here is the synchronous version of the above code

```
public interface ILocator
{
    Model Example();
}

public class Example : Controller
{
    public ILocator Locator { get; set; }

    public Example(ILocator locator)
    {
        Locator = locator;
    }

    public IActionResult Example()
    {
        Model model = Locator.Example();

        return View(model);
    }
}

public class Locator : ILocator
{
    pubilc Example()
    {
        Example model = new Example();
        model.Status = "New";
    }
}
```

Will the asynchronous version of the code have higher cost/lower performance than the synchronous version due to the unnecessary `await/async` usage?

When will `async/await` do more harm than good?

Comment: Yes, the async version will consume more CPU cycles and memory.  It is technically slower.  There's overhead to it and someone smarter than me can elaborate exactly what the overhead is.  If something takes 100 CPU cycles to complete, for example, I wouldn't make that async.  You could read the produced IL if you wanted to see the impl.

Comment: I like your question, I'm looking forward to seeing what the experts say... My answer would be `await/async` rarely (never?) increases performance, most perceived improvements in performance are just an illusion.

Comment: Which is faster? [`QueryLightBulbFrobStatusEx()` or `__WGetBulbFrobberState2()`](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)? Have you tried to benchmark? There is no *general* answer to your question (like: "if your method has 10 lines of code or more, use `async`" or something)

Comment: @dymanoid as you can see both methods have the identical code the only difference is that await/async call

Comment: This 100% depends on what your  method is doing inside it's body. No right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I  have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 based project written using C#.

That means that async/await will allow you to increase your *capacity* (in requests pers second) a great deal.

> at what point using async/await will hurt performance?

it will add a little bit of overhead that is a fixed amount. It will in general be small compared to the costs of the I/O and not really noticable.

> When will async/await do more harm than good?

In a web site/service that will never see a load above ~50 requests / second.
And even then the 'harm' will be very small.

Actual numbers depend on the hardware, amount of I/O work etc.

> In reality, that code does not need to be called asynchronously since all the code is executed in memory

In that case it will be faster to handle it synchronously.
But I know teams that prefer to have all Actions async, just for uniformity. And since the overhead is so small I consider that a valid approach too.

Answer (score 10):

You typically use `async/await` when performing I/O bound tasks like reading from a stream, reading from a DB, sending something over the network or waiting for a response.

This makes the thread available to do some other (CPU related work).

Technically, async/await is slower in terms of raw performance, however, it increases the scalability of your application since it allows threads to be available for other work while others are waiting for I/O bound operations.

Comment: True, but it's important to note it's also useful for CPU bound work.  I don't need 1 core pegged to 100% usage while my other cores are yawning.

Comment: Yes with the example in the OP I am not accessing any external resource. However, what if a need comes along (a year later) which requires me to create another implementation to the `ILocator` but this time the implementation will perform some I/O work. If my interface does not define `Task<Model> ModelAsync()` then my I/O work will have to be done synchronously.

Comment: @John That's where planning comes in. If you anticipate a need for Async, then perhaps taking the slight performance hit now is acceptable so that it will work later.  There's no right or wrong answer, you just need to think through your own situation.